# AngularJS How to parse html into directive template

Tags: angularjs

How i can parse html in directive template???

```js
app.directive('user', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    template: '<div class="clearfix buttons-container" ng-bind-html-unsafe="current_text"></div>'
  }
});


//in controller
$scope.current_text = 'Hello <strong>'+current_username+'</strong> !!!'
```

Comment: What do you mean by parse? What do you intend to do with the HTML template?

Comment: just compiling <strong> tag in browser

Comment: You need to check out [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Comment: have u inject ng-sanatize in your module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$sce.trustAsHtml`. this method will create trusted HTML object for `ng-bind-html` directive.

**[$sce.trustAsHtml Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml)**

See below example

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $sce) {

  var current_username = "User";
  var html = 'Hello <strong>' + current_username + '</strong> !!!';
  $scope.current_text = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);

});

app.directive('user', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    template: '<div class="clearfix buttons-container" ng-bind-html="current_text"></div>'
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <user></user>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using **isolate-scope**
in this way.

```
app.directive('user', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        current_text : '@current_text'
    },

    template: '<div class="clearfix buttons-container" ng-bind-html-unsafe="current_text"></div>'
  }
});


//in controller
$scope.currenText = 'Hello <strong>'+current_username+'</strong> !!!'

<div current_text="currenText" > </div> // your directive included here
```